# Where to write associations in Single Table Inheritance in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, single-table-inheritance

I have a base class called User and it has 2 subclasses named Manager and Creator. I have implemented Single Table Inheritance for User, Manager and Creator models. 
There are 2 other models named Project and Bug.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
end

class Manager < User
end

class Creator < User
end

class Project < ApplicationRecord
end

class Bug < ApplicationRecord
end
```

The associations I want to have are

- A Project can have many Users
- A Manager can have many Projects
- A Creator can create many Bugs

I understand the relations but I am unable to understand where to put the associations(for the User and it's subclasses). 
 
For example 
For the association: A Creator can create many Bugs

```
class Creator < User
   has_many :bugs
end
```

Where do I put the other side of the association declaration? Do I write it inside the User class or the Creator class? 
i.e

```
class Bug < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :user
end
```

or

```
class Bug < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :creator
end
```

Which one is the right way to do it? 
The bottom line of the question is: 
In Single Table Inheritance do I make associations(of other models) with the parent model or the child model?

Comment: `User`, `Manager`, and `Creator` all look like roles held by a `Person`. I don't know anything about your domain, but STI would not be my go-to approach here.

Comment: what do you suggest instead of STI? I am supposed to have all these entities, as a part of my domain models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to your comment, below is a potential way to model the associations you enumerate using only `User`, `Project`, `Bug`, and `ProjectUser` without STI.

A simple way to model `A Creator can create many Bugs` might be something like:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :bugs, foreign_key: :creator_id
end
```

And for your `Bug` model:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: bugs
#
#  id                     :integer          not null, primary key
#  creator_id             :integer
#  created_at             :datetime         not null
#  updated_at             :datetime         not null
#
class Bug < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :creator, class_name: 'User'
end
```

In this case, the role is implied by the association definition, but you don't have an explicit `Role` model. So if you have an instance of `@user`, you could do something like:

```
@user.bugs.create bug_attributes
```

If you have an `@bug`, then you can do:

```
@bug.creator
```

...and get back the `User` that created the `Bug`.

Similarly, to model `A Manager can have many Projects`, you could do something like:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :bugs, foreign_key: :creator_id
  has_many :managed_projects, class_name: 'Project', foreign_key: :manager_id
end

# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: projects
#
#  id                     :integer          not null, primary key
#  manager_id             :integer
#  created_at             :datetime         not null
#  updated_at             :datetime         not null
#
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :manager, class_name: 'User'
end
```

Again, the role is implicit to the association definition. And, with `@user`, you can do:

```
@user.managed_projects.create project_attributes
```

To model `A Project can have many Users` (assuming that a `User can belong to many projects`), you could use a `ProjectUser` model that might look something like:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: project_users
#
#  id                     :integer          not null, primary key
#  project_id             :integer
#  user_id                :integer
#  created_at             :datetime         not null
#  updated_at             :datetime         not null
#
class ProjectUser < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Then in your `Project`, you could do:

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :manager, class_name: 'User'
  has_many :project_users
  has_many :users, through: :project_users
end
```

And in your `User`, you could do:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :bugs, foreign_key: :creator_id
  has_many :managed_projects, class_name: 'Project', foreign_key: :manager_id
  has_many :project_users
  has_many :projects, through: :project_users
end
```

Now you can do things like `@project.users` and `@user.projects`.

Depending on your domain and use cases, you might want to make `Role` an explicit class. But, that's a whole other kettle of fish.